# Determining the matrix representation of a linear transformation. $P_2$ to $P_2$

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T$ be the linear transformation from $P_2$ to $P_2$ defined by : $$T(a+bx+c x^2 )=b-2cx+a x^2 $$

Attempt:

I used the standard basis. $(1,x, x^2 )$

$$T(1)=a$$

$$T(x)=b$$

$$T( x^2 )=-2c$$

Then I get the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint***

you have that
$$T(a+bx+cx^2 )=b-2cx+ax^2 $$
T is linear so :
$$ \implies aT(1)+bT(x)+cT(x^2)=b-2cx+a x^2 $$
To get $T(1)$ you need $a=1, b=c=0$
$$T(1)=x^2$$
To get $T(x)$ you need $a=c=0, b=1$
$$T(x)=1$$
To get $T(x^2)$ you need $a=b=0,c=1$
$$T(x^2)=-2x$$
Therefore 
$$A=\pmatrix {0&1&0\\0&0&-2\\1&0 &0}$$

Answer (score 1):

$T(1),T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$ are not correct.

$T(1)=x^2$, $T(x)=1$, $T(x^2)=-2x$.

Let $\beta=\{1,x,x^2\}$ then $$[T]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&-2\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$